# no puedo aplicar efecto masonry en mi angular 8

Tags: angular, plugin

espero que estén muy bien , este será mi segundo post, así que intentare ser lo mas detallista posible.
Mi problema es el siguiente , estoy buscando tener un estilo pinterest en mi app de angular 8 , al encontrar masonry y sus funcionalidades me intereso mucho , al momento de compilar mi app , sube las imágenes pero no se le aplica su efecto. busque y no encontré mucha documentación que me pueda ayudar , si alguien tiene el mismo problema y puede ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho, a continuación dejo mi código para que puedan darme una mano.

> package.json
>    `"ngx-masonry": "^1.1.4",`

> component.ts

```
import { NgxMasonryModule } from 'ngx-masonry';
import { MasonryGalleryModule } from 'ngx-masonry-gallery';

import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-seccion',
  templateUrl: './seccion.component.html',

  providers:[NoticiasService],

  styleUrls: ['./seccion.component.css']
})

export class SeccionComponent implements OnInit {
public economias: Economia[] ;
public medicinas: Medicina[] ;
public tecnologias: Tecnologia[] ;
public politicas: Politica[];
public url: string;


public myOptions: MasonryOptions = {
  gutter: 10,
  columnWidth: 250
};
```

> archivo.scss

```
ngx-masonry{
  width: 30%;
  img{
    max-width: 300px;
  }
}
```

> mi html

```
<div class="cont-noticias">

  <ngx-masonry  [options]="{ gutter: 10 }" *ngFor="let economia of economias"  >
    <div myOptions class="contenedor-contenido" >
                      <img src="{{ url+'get-image/'+economia.imageM }}" class="imagen-muestra" alt="{{ economia.title }}" min-width="100px">
                      <div class="contenedor-info">
                          <div >
                              <h6 class="subtitulo">{{ economia.subtitulo }}</h6>
                          </div>
                          <div>

                                  <span>{{economia.year}}</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
      </div>
   </ngx-masonry>


 </div>
```

> vista de mi html
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> vista de mi cmd
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**fuentes**

> https://github.com/wynfred/ngx-masonry
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-masonry

Comment: Tienes un error en la consola, deberías corregirlo primero. Y en el html `<div myOptions class="contenedor-contenido" >`  `myOptions` no debería ir ahí.

Comment: tienes alguna sugerencia para arreglar ese error por consola ? ya que tengo todo declarado... deberia verificar el angular.json ? y de ser asi, donde deberia declararlo ?

Comment: Importaste el módulo en el app.module.ts? Veo que lo estás importando en el componente `SeccionComponent`

Comment: sii , lo tengo tambien declarado, lo has usado y te ha funcionado ?? intentare declararlo en angular.json en scripts

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo los pasos de la documentación:

1. Instalar

   ```
   npm install ngx-masonry masonry-layout --save
   ```
2. Importar en app.module

   ```
   import { NgxMasonryModule } from 'ngx-masonry';

   @NgModule({
   imports: [NgxMasonryModule]
   })
   ```

Con esos dos pasos ya se pueden probar los ejemplos tal cual están en la documentación. **NOTA**: Debe usarse `NgxMasonryOptions` en lugar de `MasonryOptions`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxMasonryOptions } from 'ngx-masonry';
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-app',
  template: `
  
  <ngx-masonry>
       <div ngxMasonryItem [options]="myOptions" class="masonry-item" *ngFor="let item of masonryItems">
        {{item.title}}
        <img src="{{item.image}}">
      </div>
     </ngx-masonry>
  
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .masonry-item { width: 200px; }
    `
  ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  masonryItems = [
    { title: 'item 1', image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/190.png/09f/fff' },
    { title: 'item 2', image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/175.png/09f/fff' },
    { title: 'item 3', image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/180.png/09f/fff' },
  ];

  public myOptions: NgxMasonryOptions = {
    gutter: 10
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

Comment: como me gustaria darte un abrazo en estos momentos. muchas gracias por tu ayuda, lo voy a probar